# Remove a member from a group using Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library

Tags: c#, azure, office365, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

What is the correct way to remove a member from a group using the [Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet)?

Adding a member can be done like this:

```
client.Groups["groupid"].Members.References.Request().AddAsync(objToAdd);
```

So i expected that there is something like:

```
client.Groups["groupid"].Members.References.Request().RemoveAsync(objToRemove);
```

The same question also applies to client.Groups["groupid"].Owners.References.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this way:

```
client.Groups["group_id"].Members["member_id"].Reference.Request().DeleteAsync();
```

The API to remove a member is:

```
DELETE /groups/<id>/members/<id>/$ref
```

The DirectoryObjectReferenceRequest.DeleteAsync() method will use **DELETE** method to send the request.

Comment: Just what I was missing - thanx

Comment: It's worth noting that currently that command will delete the user from the directory entirely.  Currently searching for an alternative.

Comment: @RobertFoster For me it works perfectly. Thanks to Jeffrey.

Comment: @RobertFoster No this will only delete the reference in the group membership listing to the user directory object. The "Reference" part of the c# statement ensures that the $ref is added to the API call, hence only the reference is deleted and not the actual user directory object